# How to connect multiple POSTGRES servers using pgadmin

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

Our application has two databases in two different servers. How can I execute a query to fetch data from both the databases simultaneously. Something like a pgadmin will do.

Comment: you must need [**dblink**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/dblink.html)

Comment: `dblink` or `postgres_fdw`. Or write client code to do it. What did you try before posting? You say "like pgadmin" ... but then "using pgadmin". Which is it?

Comment: i need some db client using which i can write a query which can fetch data from two different databases